# Restrict loaded content to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page that is basically this:

```
<div id="thelist" style="height:100%; width:100%; position:relative"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#thelist').load('other.aspx', function () { });
</script>
```

The problem is this:  When the content is loaded, it expands outside the boundaries of the div and into surrounding controls.  Is there a way to restrict this content to the div and just have the div scroll to include all the contents?  Thanks.

Comment: if you want the div to scroll have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this with the css `overflow` property setting it to either `auto` or `scroll`.
Here's [a good article](http://css-tricks.com/2833-the-css-overflow-property/) detailing the ins and out and here is the [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html).

Comment: Ugh, thanks a lot.  I had tried that but it was wrapped inside another div that was cancelling it out in some manner.

Comment: So you just need to find the 'in some manner'. ;-) Load up the page with a development tool (eg. Firebug) to see which styles are cancelling it and/or not being applied. In any event, the JavaScript part of your equation was right all along and it's now a CSS question.

Comment: The div was actually a fix to another problem that was solved long ago, and is no longer necessary.  Remove the second div, issue solved.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the div element's overflow to hidden as a style

```
div#thelist {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="thelist" style="height:100%; width:100%;
position:relative; overflow:auto/scroll"></div>
```